# Error: failed linking file resources

Tags: android, main-activity, aapt2

Every time I am trying to turn on my app it shows up an error:

```
Error:error: '*/*' is incompatible with attribute android:type (attr) enum [linear=0, radial=1, sweep=2].
Error:'*/*' is incompatible with attribute android:type (attr) enum [linear=0, radial=1, sweep=2].
Error:failed linking file resources.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

The code looks fine (I guess) but I was doing the reinstallation of system while making this app. What kind of files am I missing? Which one were not copied?

Comment: Although you mention the code "looks fine", there's no way for anyone else to determine that :) You should try to provide at least some code. Here's a guide on how to format it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Cheers!

Comment: As I see in ASP, program has a problem with:     tools:context=".MainActivity"

Comment: @Johanna looks like in one of your XML files you're using 'android:type="*/*"', and the value "*/*" is incorrect. Can you check where you're using it and post the contents?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, But I solved it by updating to the latest Gradle plugin version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I forgot to delete all files from a settings activity (there was some XML files mentioning things that I deleted). So I deleted these XML files (since they were useless, in my case) and then the error disappeared. So you might check if some XML file is mentioning something that you've previously deleted, renamed or something that does not exist (maybe a typo).